# ClassNotFoundException In Gradle when switched to Groovy 2.0

Tags: groovy, gradle

I were using Gradle to manage Groovy project. Groovy was set to 1.8.6 and then I wanted to switch to Groovy 2.0. When I do that I get:

```
:compileGroovy

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileGroovy'.
> groovy/util/AntBuilder
```

Same thing happens if I run it from STS or command line.

Any ideas what I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ant support is now in a separate module. You need to add a dependency on `groovy-ant` too.